# Serializing and unseralizing JSON as a database

Tags: php, database, json

I would like to distribute my web application (php) without the need of having a database as a dependency. My first idea was to just store json strings to disk. Serialize this string whenever I needed to fetch the data. This however can become quite slow for large data-sets. Are there ways of doing this without the need of a dependency and to make it sort of usuable so that large data won't make it really slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to use the built in [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) support rather than a JSON based solution.

This will allow you to create SQL tables that are processed "in memory" and backed to standard text files on disk for storage, hence removing the need for a MySQL, etc. database to be set up and configured.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use SQLite instead. This is a server-less DBMS: the database is just stored on the disk, where you want, and you can create it on the fly, during script installation.

So the only dependency will be the php-sqlite extension, which is now enabled by default in PHP.

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

You can even use a DBAL or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) to keep your code independent from the DBMS, and allow users to choose from SQLite or any other DBMS you may want to support.

Comment: From http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php - "As of PHP 5 this extension is enabled by default, so simply do not disable it and it'll be available.".